# What actually occurs within UNIX OS upon swapping shells

Tags: shell, unix

I am currently learning UNIX and all going okay.  Just covered the different shells, i.e. Bourne SHell (sh), Bourne Again SHell (BASH) and Korn SHell (KSH) etc and I understand that going into the different shells makes different functionality available via commands to other apps etc.  But what I am unclear about is what "switches" in the UNIX OS when say I go from sh to ksh??  Is it just that it goes to a different location in the file structure or what??

Comment: The shell is what's providing that functionality at all. It's not like there's some separate thing that uses a shell under the hood and makes a decision about which shell it's using -- it's directly the shell itself that provides the prompt that you're typing into.

Comment: Also, "makes different functionality to other apps" is simply false. Applications don't call the parent shell that invoked them; they typically call `/bin/sh` when they want to run a shell command, and which shell that is doesn't change based on which interactive shell the user selects. (Running `sh` on a POSIX system is supposed to be a guarantee of getting a POSIX-compliant shell, but all of POSIX sh, bash, and ksh are POSIX-compliant. Bourne sh is not POSIX-compliant -- the standard came out in 1991 and Bourne is from the 70s -- but nobody ships Bourne anymore).

Comment: ...so, the claim in your question that `sh` is Bourne shell is itself a misunderstanding; the only OS vendor to have even *shipped* Bourne in decades is Sun, and they've finally stopped that; everywhere sane, `/bin/sh` is something like ash or dash, and properly POSIX sh compliant, not Bourne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that going into the different shells makes different functionality via commands to other apps etc.

This is incorrect.

Which shell you're interactively using as a user *has no bearing* on which shell applications use when they use the `system()` C library call or any equivalent to same (which well-written applications don't do in the first place: Good practice is to directly invoke an `exec`-family call to start an external command when needed, not to use an interim shell at all). Thus, there is no mechanism for the user's interactive shell to select how applications behave, because it doesn't in fact make any such selection.

When your shell is, say, `ksh`, it's ksh providing the actual interactive prompt you're typing into; comparing the commands you type to its aliases, functions and builtins, and finding an external command to run should you pass it such -- but if you pass an external command, once that command is running it has no knowledge of which shell invoked it (unless that information is exported in an environment variable such as `$SHELL`), and does not change its behavior based on same.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I stand corrected.  I am using a training DVD purchased some years ago.  I will find a more recent training media before continuing

Comment: I'd suggest http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/ and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide as good places to start for sound information about bash in particular, or POSIX-compliant shells in general.